# Programming in prolog with if and only if

Tags: prolog

I'm struggling to understand why my solutions to "Implement a predicate `find_in(X,Y)` that is true if X is in Y or X can be found in an object in Y."
I came up with a solution  with

```
find_in(X,Y):-in(X,Y);in(Y,Z),in(Z,X)
```

but it is wrong so i want to know how to do it properly  and understand why my answer is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in Dirk's answer you probably swapped `X` and `Y`. 
For clearance I would split the cases.

```
find_in(X,Y) :- in(X,Y).
find_in(X,Y) :- in(X,Z), in(Z,Y).
```

As an addition you may want to go multiple levels deep. Which is just a small adjustment.

```
find_in(X,Y) :- in(X,Y).
find_in(X,Y) :- in(X,Z), find_in(Z,Y).
```

So for example if `a` is in `b`, `b` is in `c`, and so on.. `find_in(a,z)` will evaluate to true as well.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you swapped X and Y in the second part of your clause:

```
find_in(X,Y):-in(X,Y);in(X,Z),in(Z,Y).
```

EDIT: added the missing '.' at the end of the clause.

Comment: No particular reason.  In fact the OP did not have the syntax error - it came in during one edit.  I tried to correct it (re-adding it to the question), but edits of less than 6 characters are not allowed.

Comment: s(X). Thx 4 explaining.